# React useReducer: state not being updated

Tags: reactjs

Could someone please help me figure out what is wrong with my code. I created the Following initial state:

```
  const initialIsTouched =
  {
    itemOne:false,
    itemTwo: false
  };
```

I set up the following reducer function:

```
  const formReducer = (state, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOUCHED':
      if (action.id == 'itemOne') {
        return {
        [state.itemOne]: true,
        [state.itemTwo]: false
        }               
      }
      if (action.id == 'itemTwo') {
        return {
        [state.itemOne]: false,
        [state.itemTwo]: true
        }              
      }      
    default:
      return state;  
  }
};
```

And I dispatched my action thusly:

```
const touchedHandler = event => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'TOUCHED',
    id: event.target.id
  });
};
```

Could someone please explain to me what I did wrong? My state is not being updated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please use `usereducer` hooks for that type of thing. in your so many error like state return statement and discpatch is undifined etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const formReducer = (state, action) => {

   switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOUCHED':
    if (action.id == 'itemOne') {
      return {
       itemOne: true,
       itemTwo: false
      }               
    }
    if (action.id == 'itemTwo') {
      return {
        itemOne: false,
        itemTwo: true
      }              
    }      
    default:
       return state;  
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look I hope you get what you want.

we can achieve this type of thing by using `useReducer` hooks.

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';

const initialState = {
    itemOne: true,
    itemTwo: false
}
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOUCHED':
    if (action.id == 'itemOne') {
      return {
       itemOne: true,
       itemTwo: false
      }               
    }
    if (action.id == 'itemTwo') {
      return {
        itemOne: false,
        itemTwo: true
      }              
    }      
    default:
       return state;  
   }
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const touchedHandler = event => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'TOUCHED',
    id: event.target.id
  });
};
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply. Your solution works!